# How to stop an active publishing process without recycling app pool

Tags: publishing

I've ran publish process and forgot to uncheck republish checkbox. Now I need to wait while publishing finish.
How I can stop publish process without recycling app pool?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the server, you can upload a package and you will get the option to restart the sitecore server when it is done. I know this isn't the exact answer to your solution, but it is helpful if the only issues is that you don't have access to the App Pool to recycle it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Sitecore Client does not have such feature like to view and terminate current running task. The only way would be recycle Sitecore's Application Pool to stop publishing process.

On Sitecore Marketplace, I found the Advanced Publish Dialog shared source module supports canceling currently running publishing job:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_Publish_Dialog.aspx

Problem is this module is old, I am not sure if it works on new versions of Sitecore

Comment: I don't think that module even really aborted the publish.  It just used reflection to call `JobManager.FinishJob` which just sets the status of the job to `Finished` and moves it from the running jobs list to the finished jobs list.  It doesn't (and couldn't) abort the thread.